# How can I identify sequences used by tables?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sequence

Is there a way to query an Oracle database that would return:

- a listing of all the tables in the database
- which sequence it is using (if any)

Comment: You can't. Oracle simply doesn't store that dependency

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, how do you come to this statement?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5dc2e9f5ab0e32308afa997057efa425

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - strange, why is my solution working then? Well, IDENTITY are not covered as I stated. But typically these sequences are hidden anyway.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: your solution only detects dependencies between triggers and sequences, not between tables and sequences. My example doesn't use an IDENTITY column, just a default value based on a sequence

Comment: What do you mean by "which sequence it is using"? Using for what, and how?

Answer (score 1):

You can query with this one:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_OWNER, TABLE_NAME, 
    REFERENCED_OWNER AS SEQUENCE_OWNER, REFERENCED_NAME AS SEQUENCE_NAME
FROM ALL_DEPENDENCIES d
    JOIN ALL_TRIGGERS t ON TRIGGER_NAME = d.NAME AND t.OWNER = d.OWNER
WHERE REFERENCED_TYPE = 'SEQUENCE';
```

Note, a sequence might be used by more than one trigger. And a sequence can be used also by function, procedure, package, insert, update, etc, which is not covered by this query.

Also this query does not cover `IDENTITY` columns and sequences, they are hidden.

It depends what you mean by "identify sequences used by tables"?

Comment: This assumes as well that there is a trigger populating the key.  Most of the systems I've been involved with use sequences to generate the keys but don't use triggers.  The sequence is specified as part of the `insert` statement.  It may also incorrectly flag dependencies when, for example, a trigger gets the `currval` of a sequence other than the one it uses for the primary key for some reason.

Comment: @JustinCave, I would assume, prior 12c SEQUENCE + TRIGGER was the typical method to generate primary keys. Maybe you grew up in different environment than I did.

Comment: That's not my experience.  Certainly there were cases where triggers were used.  But less than 50% in my personal sample size.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit in my experience the use of triggers to populate ID columns is rare. I certainly wouldn't count on it as a way of linking tables to sequences.